# where to copy servlet files in apache tomcat server to work fine with web?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Can anyone guide me how to get Servlets working in Apache Tomcat server? I can run the Servlets from Netbeans without problems, but I don't know where to put the class files in Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In tomcat:

- class files must be in `TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/<yourAppName>/WEB-INF/classes`
- jar files must be in `TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/<yourAppName>/WEB-INF/lib`

(and if course you'll need `web.xml` in `WEB-INF`)

Answer (score 1):

They go in `Tomcat/webapps` folder. There are several ways to deploy a JSP/Servlet webapplication on Tomcat. They are all described in [Tomcat Web Application Deployment HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).

If you already have developed the webapplication in Netbeans, then Netbeans should already have build a WAR file of it in the `/dist` folder. You just need to drop the WAR file in `Tomcat/webapps` folder and Tomcat will automatically deploy it during startup (or even while running, this is called *hotdeploy*).

If you want to develop without an IDE and/or don't want to create a WAR, then you just need to put a folder representing the context name in `Tomcat/webapps`, e.g. `Tomcat/webapps/contextname`. It will become the public web content. You can drop all JSP files and other static files in there. Then, for classes you need to create a `Tomcat/webapps/contextname/WEB-INF/classes` folder. There should go the package structure.